# Cant connect to airflow webserver

Tags: airflow

I cant connect to the webserver after I init my Airflow. These are steps I did:

1. `pip3 install apache-airflow`
2. `mkdir ~/airflow`
3. `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`
4. `airflow initdb`
5. `airflow webserver -p 8080`

Can anyone tell me why it shows as below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error `Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8080)` means that the port is used by another service, and you cannot run your airflow webserver on the same port, so try to use another port:

```bash
airflow webserver -p 8088
```

Then in your browser try with new url

```
http://localhost:8088/
```